# Code from Form1.vb has disappear

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, visual-studio

I have a bit of situation. I am using Visual Studio 2017. My code from `Form1.vb` is gone. All of the components are saved in the `Form1.Designer.vb`. But I cannot restore it.

Here is my code form the `Form1.Designer.vb`:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Partial Class NotePadApp
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Dim resources As System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(NotePadApp))
    Me.MenuBar = New System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip()
    Me.FileToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.NewToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.OpenToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.SaveToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.SaveAsToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.ToolStripSeparator1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator()
    Me.ExitToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.EditToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.FontToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.ToolStripSeparator5 = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator()
    Me.UndoToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.ToolStripSeparator2 = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator()
    Me.CutToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.CopyToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.PasteToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.ToolStripSeparator3 = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator()
    Me.FindToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.ReplaceToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.ToolStripSeparator4 = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator()
    Me.SelectAllToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.ViewToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.RichTextBox = New System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox()
    Me.EventLog1 = New System.Diagnostics.EventLog()
    Me.ThemesToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.EyesFriendlyToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.WhiteToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.DarkToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
    Me.MenuBar.SuspendLayout()
    CType(Me.EventLog1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'MenuBar
    '
    Me.MenuBar.ImageScalingSize = New System.Drawing.Size(20, 20)
    Me.MenuBar.Items.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem() {Me.FileToolStripMenuItem, Me.EditToolStripMenuItem, Me.ViewToolStripMenuItem})
    Me.MenuBar.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
    Me.MenuBar.Name = "MenuBar"
    Me.MenuBar.Padding = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5, 2, 0, 2)
    Me.MenuBar.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1085, 28)
    Me.MenuBar.TabIndex = 0
    Me.MenuBar.Text = "MenuStrip1"
    '
    'FileToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.FileToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem() {Me.NewToolStripMenuItem, Me.OpenToolStripMenuItem, Me.SaveToolStripMenuItem, Me.SaveAsToolStripMenuItem, Me.ToolStripSeparator1, Me.ExitToolStripMenuItem})
    Me.FileToolStripMenuItem.Name = "FileToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.FileToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(44, 24)
    Me.FileToolStripMenuItem.Text = "File"
    '
    'NewToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.NewToolStripMenuItem.Name = "NewToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.NewToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(181, 26)
    Me.NewToolStripMenuItem.Text = "New"
    '
    'OpenToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.OpenToolStripMenuItem.Name = "OpenToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.OpenToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(181, 26)
    Me.OpenToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Open..."
    '
    'SaveToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.SaveToolStripMenuItem.Name = "SaveToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.SaveToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(181, 26)
    Me.SaveToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Save"
    '
    'SaveAsToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.SaveAsToolStripMenuItem.Name = "SaveAsToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.SaveAsToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(181, 26)
    Me.SaveAsToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Save As..."
    '
    'ToolStripSeparator1
    '
    Me.ToolStripSeparator1.Name = "ToolStripSeparator1"
    Me.ToolStripSeparator1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(178, 6)
    '
    'ExitToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.ExitToolStripMenuItem.Name = "ExitToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.ExitToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(181, 26)
    Me.ExitToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Exit"
    '
    'EditToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.EditToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem() {Me.FontToolStripMenuItem, Me.ToolStripSeparator5, Me.UndoToolStripMenuItem, Me.ToolStripSeparator2, Me.CutToolStripMenuItem, Me.CopyToolStripMenuItem, Me.PasteToolStripMenuItem, Me.ToolStripSeparator3, Me.FindToolStripMenuItem, Me.ReplaceToolStripMenuItem, Me.ToolStripSeparator4, Me.SelectAllToolStripMenuItem})
    Me.EditToolStripMenuItem.Name = "EditToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.EditToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(47, 24)
    Me.EditToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Edit"
    '
    'FontToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.FontToolStripMenuItem.Name = "FontToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.FontToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(146, 26)
    Me.FontToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Font"
    '
    'ToolStripSeparator5
    '
    Me.ToolStripSeparator5.Name = "ToolStripSeparator5"
    Me.ToolStripSeparator5.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(143, 6)
    '
    'UndoToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.UndoToolStripMenuItem.Name = "UndoToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.UndoToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(146, 26)
    Me.UndoToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Undo"
    '
    'ToolStripSeparator2
    '
    Me.ToolStripSeparator2.Name = "ToolStripSeparator2"
    Me.ToolStripSeparator2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(143, 6)
    '
    'CutToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.CutToolStripMenuItem.Name = "CutToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.CutToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(146, 26)
    Me.CutToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Cut"
    '
    'CopyToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.CopyToolStripMenuItem.Name = "CopyToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.CopyToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(146, 26)
    Me.CopyToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Copy"
    '
    'PasteToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.PasteToolStripMenuItem.Name = "PasteToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.PasteToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(146, 26)
    Me.PasteToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Paste"
    '
    'ToolStripSeparator3
    '
    Me.ToolStripSeparator3.Name = "ToolStripSeparator3"
    Me.ToolStripSeparator3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(143, 6)
    '
    'FindToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.FindToolStripMenuItem.Name = "FindToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.FindToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(146, 26)
    Me.FindToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Find"
    '
    'ReplaceToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.ReplaceToolStripMenuItem.Name = "ReplaceToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.ReplaceToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(146, 26)
    Me.ReplaceToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Replace"
    '
    'ToolStripSeparator4
    '
    Me.ToolStripSeparator4.Name = "ToolStripSeparator4"
    Me.ToolStripSeparator4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(143, 6)
    '
    'SelectAllToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.SelectAllToolStripMenuItem.Name = "SelectAllToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.SelectAllToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(146, 26)
    Me.SelectAllToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Select All"
    '
    'ViewToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.ViewToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem() {Me.ThemesToolStripMenuItem})
    Me.ViewToolStripMenuItem.Name = "ViewToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.ViewToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(53, 24)
    Me.ViewToolStripMenuItem.Text = "View"
    '
    'RichTextBox
    '
    Me.RichTextBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window
    Me.RichTextBox.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
    Me.RichTextBox.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
    Me.RichTextBox.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 10.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.RichTextBox.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
    Me.RichTextBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 28)
    Me.RichTextBox.Name = "RichTextBox"
    Me.RichTextBox.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxScrollBars.ForcedBoth
    Me.RichTextBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1085, 544)
    Me.RichTextBox.TabIndex = 1
    Me.RichTextBox.Text = ""
    Me.RichTextBox.WordWrap = False
    '
    'EventLog1
    '
    Me.EventLog1.SynchronizingObject = Me
    '
    'ThemesToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.ThemesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem() {Me.EyesFriendlyToolStripMenuItem, Me.WhiteToolStripMenuItem, Me.DarkToolStripMenuItem})
    Me.ThemesToolStripMenuItem.Name = "ThemesToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.ThemesToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(181, 26)
    Me.ThemesToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Themes"
    '
    'EyesFriendlyToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.EyesFriendlyToolStripMenuItem.Checked = True
    Me.EyesFriendlyToolStripMenuItem.CheckState = System.Windows.Forms.CheckState.Checked
    Me.EyesFriendlyToolStripMenuItem.Name = "EyesFriendlyToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.EyesFriendlyToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(181, 26)
    Me.EyesFriendlyToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Eyes Friendly"
    '
    'WhiteToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.WhiteToolStripMenuItem.Name = "WhiteToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.WhiteToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(181, 26)
    Me.WhiteToolStripMenuItem.Text = "White"
    '
    'DarkToolStripMenuItem
    '
    Me.DarkToolStripMenuItem.Name = "DarkToolStripMenuItem"
    Me.DarkToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(181, 26)
    Me.DarkToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Dark"
    '
    'NotePadApp
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(8.0!, 16.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(1085, 572)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.RichTextBox)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.MenuBar)
    Me.Icon = CType(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon"), System.Drawing.Icon)
    Me.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 2, 3, 2)
    Me.Name = "NotePadApp"
    Me.Text = "NotePadApp"
    Me.MenuBar.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.MenuBar.PerformLayout()
    CType(Me.EventLog1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.PerformLayout()

End Sub

Friend WithEvents MenuBar As MenuStrip
Friend WithEvents FileToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents OpenToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents SaveAsToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents NewToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents SaveToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents ToolStripSeparator1 As ToolStripSeparator
Friend WithEvents ExitToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents EditToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents FontToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents ToolStripSeparator5 As ToolStripSeparator
Friend WithEvents UndoToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents ToolStripSeparator2 As ToolStripSeparator
Friend WithEvents CutToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents CopyToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents PasteToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents ToolStripSeparator3 As ToolStripSeparator
Friend WithEvents FindToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents ReplaceToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents ToolStripSeparator4 As ToolStripSeparator
Friend WithEvents SelectAllToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents ViewToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents RichTextBox As RichTextBox
Friend WithEvents EventLog1 As EventLog
Friend WithEvents ThemesToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents EyesFriendlyToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents WhiteToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
Friend WithEvents DarkToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
End Class
```

Any suggestions how I can revert that. 
Also i do not have a backup since i started the project like two days ago.

Any help is welcomed!

Best regards,

Dimitar Georgiev

Comment: Save often, use source control.

Comment: Check it from recycle bin ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you open the file location and right click on the file, there's an option to restore previous versions. If you're lucky, there might be something there.  Good luck.

[image]